# Specific Integral identities for rational functions

Tags: resource-recommendations, feynman-diagrams, integration

I have a set of exactly 12 integrals for which I want to find (if existing) analytical solutions. I know they must exist for some of them but I cannot find a credible source where they are written down. Since they appear e.g. in calculating total cross sections of certain processes in QFT I was hoping that you could point me to a valid source.
The integrals are:

$$
I_1 = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^n}{Ax+B} dx 
$$
$$
I_2 = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^n}{(Ax+B)^2} dx
$$
$$
I_3 = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^n}{(Ax+B)(Cx+D)} dx
$$

I am looking for the solutions for $1 \leq n \leq 4$ (hence the number 12) and I should specify that A,B,C,D are real numbers.

I do get solutions with Mathematica but I am not sure how much I can trust them since I see e.g. [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_rational_functions) that I should probably expect logarithms with arguments wrapped in absolute values but in Mathematica I get arguments without the absolute value function but a bunch of conditions instead.
(I am aware it should be possible to piece the full solution together based on the conditions but I would prefer seeing the full solution written down somewhere if it exists.)
On the other hand, the link above does not state any source and contains only a part of the desired functions.

All of this just leads me to think that the best solution would be to find a citeable source which I have not found so far. I would appreciate your suggestions.

Edit: I had forgotten to add the integration boundaries I am interested in. They are now there!

Comment: what sources have you already consulted?

Comment: Aside from using Mathematica and the Wikipedia article I mentioned (that does not cite any sources) I started with standard QFT books: 
    Peskin/Schroeder's "An introduction to Quantum Field Theory" and "Quantum Field Theory " by Matthew D. Schwartz .... But did not see anything there

Comment: The wiki article does state that, based on the results there, by applying partial fraction decomposition you can get to the solutions for n higher than 2.  But I would still like to be sure of the results there ... And of course I'd like to double check my calculations for the higher n... So, even though it looks like I am going to do everything by hand, I'd like to be able to compare results whenever possible

Comment: Did you tell *Mathematica* that $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are real?

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't instead to go straight to mathematics stackexchange instead? This isn't really a physics problem despite the source of said integrals.

Answer (score 0):

See

> Gradshteyn, I. S., and I. M. Ryzhik. Table of integrals, series, and products. Academic press, 2014.

Let $z_1=a+bx$, then
$$
\int \frac{x^n dx}{z_1^m}= \frac{x^n}{z_1^{m-1}(n+1-m)b}-\frac{na}{(n+1-m)b}\int \frac{x^{n-1}dx}{z_1^m} \tag{2.111.2}
$$
Your $I_2$ and $I_1$ can be brought to the form above.  There's an alternate expression for $n=m-1$.

For $m=1$, the recursion yields a series:
\begin{align}
\int \frac{x^n dx}{z_1}&= \frac{x^n}{nb}-\frac{ax^{n-1}}{(n-1)b^2}
+\frac{a^2x^{n-2}}{(n-2)b^3}+\ldots \\
&+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{a^{n-1}x}{1\cdot b^n}+\frac{(-1)^n a^n}{b^n+1}\log z_1
\tag{2.111.3}
\end{align}
The explicit series for $m=2$ is given in 2.111.4:
$$
\int \frac{x^n}{z_1^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{k a^{k-1} x^{n-k}}{(n-k)b^{k+1}}+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{a^n}{b^{n+1}z_1}+(-1)^{n+1}\frac{na^{n-1}}{b^{n+1}}\log z_1
$$

The form of your $I_3$ can be found in 2.103.5: there are two cases.

1. When $AC-B^2>0$:
   \begin{align}
   \int \frac{(Mx+N)dx}{A+2Bx+Cx^2}
   = \frac{M}{2C}\log\vert A+2Bx+Cx^2\vert + \frac{NC-MB}{C\sqrt{AC-B^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{Cx+B}{\sqrt{AC-B^2}}\right)
   \end{align}
2. When $AC-B^2<0$:
   \begin{align}
   \int \frac{(Mx+N)dx}{A+2Bx+Cx^2}
   &= \frac{M}{2C}\log\vert A+2Bx+Cx^2\vert \\
   &+ \frac{NC-MB}{C\sqrt{B^2-AC}}
   \log\vert \frac{Cx+B-\sqrt{B^2-AC}}{Cx+B+\sqrt{B^2-AC}} \vert
   \end{align}

Beyond Gradsteyn cited above, there are also very useful tables in

> Prudnikov AB. Integrals and series. Routledge; 2018.

Prudnikov overlaps Gradsteyn and also contains more obscure results, although it's more difficult to search than Gradsteyn.

Please check the original source against my typesetting.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I did not know about any of these two books. I will check both sources and answer again :)